# Option grouping for multi-select form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, multi-select

I was wondering if there is a way to group the option values within a multi-select list.

Just for a clearer view, I'm using the following form list--> http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/easy-multi-select-transfer-with-jquery.html#

i improvised the above script so that there is a parent category for a certain number of child categories. So say for eg: **Parent**: furniture. **Child**: chair, table, drawer, cabinet, bed.

I'm able to code it via php to show a very beautiful select form list with categories seperated by their parents but the problem arises when i try removing them from select box 2 back into select box 1 via jquery. The append simply return my child category back into the bottom of the lists.

Is there anyway to make it so that when user clicks on the remove button, the category will go back to under its own parent instead of the bottom of the list.

The following is the code for those who needs it.

```
                //GET CATEGORIES SELECT OPTIONS
                                            .
                                            .
                                      Database Query
                                            .
                                            .
                foreach($cat_values as $opt_values){
                                               .
                                               .
                          Database Query to check if Category have parent.
                       $cat_is_parent == "0" means the option value is the parent.
                                               .
                                               .
                    if($cat_is_parent == "0"){
                        echo '<option disabled="disabled" value="'.$opt_values[0].'" style="font-size:15px">'.$opt_values[1].'</option>';  
                    }
                    else{
                        echo '<option value="'.$opt_values[0].'">-->'.$opt_values[1].'</option>';
                    }
                }
```

Comment: The jquery is the same as in the tutorial.

Comment: Use [`optgroup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/optgroup) not `<option disabled="disabled"`. This will make moving options to a specified group of the options easier too.

Comment: Hi. thanks for the optgroup advice. Now the list looks so much better.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `.after()` function instead of `.append()`.  [As you can see in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/after/), you can specify the parent element and use the `.after()` function to place the selected element after it.

see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/gntGG/1/

when you return elements to the first list, the are always placed after the first option.

Comment: Hi. jeff, thanks for the help but i'm still unable to relate it to my case. Because user will be able to select from any of the 2 optgroup in **select box 1** and place their categories under **select box 2**. I think i will need to use .each function for each option:selected in **select box 2** but am not sure how i can set the condition so that when each selected value from **select box 2** goes back, it goes back to its respective optgroup. Advice appreciated.